# Disable automatic height from jQuery draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I have a Div with some prestyle that includes `height: 100%`

If I add jQuery draggable to the div, and moves it around it sets a fixed height on the div.

How can I disable the fixed height so it still works with the height from my stylesheet?

```
$('.DTable').draggable({
    heightStyle: '100%'
}).draggable({
    containment: "window",
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a parent element in your css

```
 .parent .DTable {height:100px;}
```

or use the !important on the hight

```
 .DTable {height:100px!important;}
```